# IronPython Sandboxing with CAS

Tags: c#, ironpython, cas, sandbox

I am trying to integrate IronPython into a C# application for scripting purposes.  I would also like the scripts to run under a set of security policies that restrict their access to the file system/network/sensitive system resources.

Research indicates that the most popular approach is to use CAS.  This works very well and it does not allow the user to use sockets, access the file system, etc.  However, when I try to inject variables for the scrip to interact with, I get a security exception every time I access certain parameters.  This only happens with variables I define in my assembly.  If I use a standard .NET type (like Dictionary) it works just fine.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Net;

namespace python_in_appdomain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Whatever
    {
        public int i;
        public Whatever(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Remoting();
        }

        public static void Remoting()
        {
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisAssembly.Location);

            AssemblyName name = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName();
            StrongName sn = new StrongName(
                new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(name.GetPublicKey()),
                name.Name,
                name.Version
            );

            PermissionSet pset = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
            pset.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
            pset.AddPermission(new ReflectionPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

            setup.PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies = new[] { sn.Name + ", PublicKey=" + sn.PublicKey.ToString() };
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup, pset, sn);

            String script = @"
d.Add('hello', 1)
w.i = 5
";

            Whatever w = new Whatever(4);
            Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string,int>();

            ScriptRuntime py = Python.CreateRuntime(domain);
            ScriptEngine engine = py.GetEngine("py");
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
            scope.SetVariable("w", w);
            scope.SetVariable("d", d);

            int result;
            Console.WriteLine(w.i);
            d.TryGetValue("hello", out result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine("-----");

            try
            {
                engine.Execute(script, scope);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }

            w = scope.GetVariable<Whatever>("w");
            d = scope.GetVariable<Dictionary<string,int>>("d");

            Console.WriteLine("-----");
            Console.WriteLine(w.i);
            d.TryGetValue("hello", out result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Commenting out the "w.i=5" on line 55 causes the program to execute normally under restricted security settings.  Setting the PermissionState to Unrestricted on line 47 allows both lines of the script to execute normally.  The following is the error message I receive:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.TypeExtensions.CreateDelegate(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type delegateType, Object target)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.Execute(String expression, ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.Execute(String expression, ScriptScope scope)
   at python_in_appdomain.Program.Remoting() in C:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IronPythonTest\IronPythonTest\Program.cs:line 7
6
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.PermissionSet
The demand was for:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>

The granted set of the failing assembly was:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
</PermissionSet>

The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
Microsoft.Dynamic, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1
The method that caused the failure was:
Int32 Run(Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file:///C:/Users/dave/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/IronPythonTest/IronPythonTest/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Dynamic.DLL

Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at System.Delegate.BindToMethodInfo(Object target, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType methodType, DelegateBindingFlags flags)
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.TypeExtensions.CreateDelegate(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type delegateType)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1.MakeUpdateDelegate()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1.GetUpdateDelegate(T& addr)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1.GetUpdateDelegate()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1.Create(CallSiteBinder binder)
   at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicOperations.GetOrCreateSite[T](CallSiteBinder siteBinder, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicOperations.GetOrCreateSite[T1,TResult](CallSiteBinder siteBinder)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.DynamicOperations.ConvertTo[T](Object obj)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ScopeGetVariable[T](Scope scope, String name)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope.GetVariable[T](String name)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope.GetVariable[T](String name)
   at python_in_appdomain.Program.Remoting() in C:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IronPythonTest\IronPythonTest\Program.cs:line 8
3
   at python_in_appdomain.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IronPythonTest\IronPythonTest\Program.
cs:line 31
```

The error is shockingly straight forward.  It says that it is expecting to have totally unrestricted access for this kind of action.  Is there any way around this?  Why does the dictionary work but my variable does not?  Is there a way for me to make IronPython treat my variable like the Dictionary?  Am I missing something very obvious?

Thank you very much for you help.

**Update 12/21/2012**

I kept messing around and came up with a solution that worked.  Creating the AppDomain like this (with the same permission object) allows everything to work.

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("IPyEngine", new Evidence(), setup, pset);
```

I can't say I totally understand why, though I can see that I'm not providing my assembly's Evidence nor am I adding any Assemblies to the trust list.  I don't want to mark this as the  answer until I know for certain I'm not doing anything monumentally stupid.

Answer (score 0):

This is suspicious:

```
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file:///C:/Users/dave/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/IronPythonTest/IronPythonTest/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Dynamic.DLL
```

I wonder if the file has a zone identifier. Can you check the file properties, and [Unblock it if necessary](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2010/09/using-downloaded-ironpython-modules.html)?

Comment: I had noticed that but didn't know about this blocking non-sense.  I unblocked all of the DLLs and the problem persists.

Comment: I did find something else though.  See the update from 12/21/2012.